# UnicodeDecodeError is raised when getting a cookie in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, unicode, character-encoding

I have a GAE project in Python where I am setting a cookie in one of my RequestHandlers with this code:

```py
self.response.headers['Set-Cookie'] = 'app=ABCD; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2020 23:59:59 GMT'
```

I checked in Chrome and I can see the cookie listed, so it appears to be working.

Then later in another RequestHandler, I get the cookie to check it:

```
appCookie = self.request.cookies['app']
```

This line gives the following error when executed:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1962: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems that it is trying to decode the incoming cookie info using an ASCII codec rather than UTF-8.

How do I force Python to use UTF-8 to decode this?

Are there any other Unicode-related gotchas that I need to be aware of as a newbie to Python and Google App Engine (but an experienced programmer in other languages)?

Here is the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4144, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4049, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 616, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3120, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3024, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2887, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
  File "/Users/ken/hgdev/juicekit/main.py", line 402, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ken/hgdev/juicekit/main.py", line 399, in main
    run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 98, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 116, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 721, in __call__
    response.wsgi_write(start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 296, in wsgi_write
    body = self.out.getvalue()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/StringIO.py", line 270, in getvalue
    self.buf += ''.join(self.buflist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1962: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you please include the complete stacktrace? The issue could be occurring in a number of places, and the full stacktrace provides a lot more detail.

Comment: As far as Unicode in Python goes, see here: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Comment: Your cookie doesn't have non-ASCII characters in it (or a position 1962), so it's completely impossible the code you're showing is actually throwing that error.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive and helpful reply Wooble.  Unfortunately, your statement makes no sense since the code is, in fact, throwing the error I stated.  Just because you don't understand it doesn't mean it's impossible.

Comment: Hi Nick...full Traceback added.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to use the `decode` function somewhat like this (cred @agf:):

```
self.request.cookies['app'].decode('utf-8')
```

[From official python documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support) (plus a couple added details):

Python’s 8-bit strings have a .decode([encoding], [errors]) method that interprets the string using the given encoding. The following example shows the string as it goes to unicode and then back to 8-bit string:

```
>>> u = unichr(40960) + u'abcd' + unichr(1972)   # Assemble a string
>>> type(u), u                                   # Examine
(<type 'unicode'>, u'\ua000abcd\u07b4')
>>> utf8_version = u.encode('utf-8')             # Encode as UTF-8
>>> type(utf8_version), utf8_version             # Examine
(<type 'str'>, '\xea\x80\x80abcd\xde\xb4')
>>> u2 = utf8_version.decode('utf-8')            # Decode using UTF-8
>>> u == u2                                      # The two strings match
True
```

Comment: Does this solve his problem? Can he just do `self.request.cookies['app'].encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: @agf: More of a demonstrative example than anything else. But I guess I should make a note of which of these functions he has to use. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that doesn't help.  I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, encode any unicode value you set in the cookies. You also need to quote them in case they can break the header:

```
import urllib

# This is the value we want to set.
initial_value = u'äëïöü'
# WebOb version that comes with SDK doesn't quote cookie values
# in the Response, neither webapp.Response. So we have to do it.
quoted_value = urllib.quote(initial_value.encode('utf-8'))

rsp = webapp.Response()
rsp.headers['Set-Cookie'] = 'app=%s; Path=/' % quoted_value
```

Now let's read the value. To test it, create a fake `Request` to test the cookie we have set. This code was extracted from a real unittest:

```
cookie = rsp.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
req = webapp.Request.blank('/', headers=[('Cookie', cookie)])

# The stored value is the same quoted value from before.
# Notice that here we use .str_cookies, not .cookies.
stored_value = req.str_cookies.get('app')
self.assertEqual(stored_value, quoted_value)
```

Our value is still encoded and quoted. We must do the reverse to get the initial one:

```
# And we can get the initial value unquoting and decoding.
final_value = urllib.unquote(stored_value).decode('utf-8')
self.assertEqual(final_value, initial_value)
```

If you can, consider using [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/). `webob.Response` does all the hard work of quoting and setting cookies, and you can set unicode values directly. See a summary of these issues [here](http://groups.google.com/group/webapp2/msg/985092351378c43e).